# how to add values in second dropdownchoice when i select value in first dropdownchoice?

Tags: java, wicket, dropdownchoice

i have two dropdownchoice,After selecting value from first dropdownchoice i need to
select   list of related values from database table and add this list into second
dropdownchoice. Here is my sample code for reference.
Give me any hint or reference.

```
 HTML:
 <select wicket:id="DDCStartDate" style=" width : 98px;"></select>
 <select wicket:id="DDCEndDate" style=" width : 98px;">.
```

Java code:

```
  final DropDownChoice DDCStartDate=new DropDownChoice("DDCStartDate",new    
         PropertyModel(collectionReportModel, "DDCStartDate"),lst);
  add(DDCStartDate);
  DDCStartDate.setOutputMarkupId(true);

  final DropDownChoice DDCEndDate=new DropDownChoice("DDCEndDate",);
  add(DDCEndDate);
  DDCEndDate.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

POJO code:

```
     private Date DDCStartDate;
private Date DDCEndDate;
    public Date getDDCStartDate() 
{
    return DDCStartDate;
}
public void setDDCStartDate(Date dDCStartDate) 
{
    DDCStartDate = dDCStartDate;
}


public Date getDDCEndDate() {
    return DDCEndDate;
}
public void setDDCEndDate(Date dDCEndDate) {
    DDCEndDate = dDCEndDate;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using an AJAX callback. Check the "Drop Down Choice Example" on Wicket Examples.

http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/

[This](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?5&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.ajax.builtin.ChoicePage) is the important file that shows you how to do this using the correct models.